# Input checkbox is not working at the second click

Tags: jquery

When the first time to press the "Select All", all the checkboxes are highlighted. But when pressed again, they are not removed. What is the problem?
Link: https://jsfiddle.net/erLqk2v9/2/

JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".select-all").click(function() {
        var checkboxes = $("form input[type=checkbox]");
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            checkboxes.prop("checked", false);
        } else {
            checkboxes.prop("checked", true);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: typo? `ckecked > checked`

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Is the select all checkbox within the same form element as the other checkboxes?

Comment: @MCMXCII yes///

Comment: it's because you're checking the checked attribute of a span element not the checkbox, so the `$(this).is(':checked')` will always be false resulting to the checkboxes getting check from the else statement

Comment: You just need to switch your true and false around. https://jsfiddle.net/p39Lgeu2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this by using `!$("#all-val").is(":checked")`

you can check the working fiddle link below.

https://jsfiddle.net/erLqk2v9/3/

Hope it works for you !!!

Comment: kindly let me know is this solved your requirement.if its working fine u can accept my answer.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to get the return values of the conditional statement the right way round, instead of inverting the statement itself, for example, you wouldn't say if the select all box isn't checked then uncheck them all, you'd say if the select all box is checked then select them all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you were checking the `:checked` on the `.select-all` `span` element. I made the change so that it checks the first checkbox, which is the first `<input type="checkbox" value="All" id="all-val">` element

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/erLqk2v9/4/

Answer (score 0):

You should make your `if` statement the other way around.

For better usability, I've also added a way, so if the user checks all checkboxes, the "Select All" is also checked:

```js
$(".select-all").change(function() {

  // If "Select All" are selected, check all checkboxes
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", true);
  }

  // If "Select All" are not selected, uncheck all checkboxes
  else {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", false);
  }
});

// If all is checked, check "Select All"
$("form input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
  // If all checkboxes are selected check, "Select All"
  if ($('form input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == $('form input[type=checkbox]').length) {
    $('.select-all').prop('checked', true);
  }

  // If all checkboxes are not selected, uncheck "Select All"
  else {
    $(".select-all").prop("checked", false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="select-all" id="checkAll">
<label for="checkAll">Check All</label>
<form>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
</form>
```